# How to add custom data to Laravel Passport API token?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel Passport and I would like to know if it is possible to add custom data to the `Laravel\Passport\Token`:

```
//This is how I create the token
$user = $request->user();
$token = $user->createToken('ACCESS_TOKEN')->accessToken;
```

I send the token to the API with the header `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`

Is there any way I can add custom information to the token? Something like this:

```
$token->customField = 'custom value';
$value = $request->user()->token()->customField;
```

I've read the [Passport Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) but there is no info about that.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported in Passport by default, [but it has been requested](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/94).

Custom data is supported by JWTs by using custom claims. Passport does not provide the ability to add custom claims to the JWT, but it looks like someone made a package to add the functionality: https://github.com/corbosman/laravel-passport-claims.

From a quick look, it looks like you'll be able to add custom claims to the JWT, but I don't see any helpers or anything for reading that data back. You'd have to parse the token and get the claim yourself:

```
$jwtParser = app()->make(\Lcobucci\JWT\Parser::class);
$claimValue = $jwtParser->parse('your-bearer-token')->getClaim('your-claim-name');
```

NB: I've never done this myself, I've never used that package, and everything here is untested.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it manually, by creating migration file with your custom field.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('oauth_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('customField',20)->after('client_id')->nullable();
    });
    
}
```

After the tokenCreate() add the filed value to the table:

```
$token = $user->createToken($user->email);
DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')
           ->where('id', $token->token->id)
           ->update(['customField' => $request->customField]);
```